# Datepicker.regional doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker attached to an input like this

```
<p>Date de signature :<input id="C42" type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100%" class="dt" /></p>
```

My javascript, I have two functions related to datepicker

```
function AppInit() {
        //On initialise le DatePicker pour chaque classe ".dt"
        $('.dt').datepicker({
        }).blur(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var maDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('', val);
            if (!maDate) {
                $(this).val('');
            } else {
                $(this).val(maDate.ddmmyyyy());
            }
        })
    }

    $(function () {
        $.datepicker.regional["fr"];

        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            constrainInput: false,        
        });
        $.datepicker.inputFormats = ["dd-mm-yy", "dd/mm/yy", "ddmmyy", "dd.mm.yy"];
        $.datepicker.originalParseDate = $.datepicker.parseDate;
        $.datepicker.parseDate = function (format, value, settings) {
            var date;

            function testParse(format, value, settings) {
                if (!date) {
                    try {
                        date = $.datepicker.originalParseDate(format, value, settings);
                    } catch (Error) {
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var n = 0, stop = $.datepicker.inputFormats ? $.datepicker.inputFormats.length : 0; n < stop; n++) {
                testParse($.datepicker.inputFormats[n], value, settings);
            };
            return date;
        };
        AppInit();
    });
```

Unfortunately, when I click the datepicker, the date is always in English. I have the "datepicker-fr.js".

I tried on a blank page with the same calls etc and it works.

Can you help me ?

Comment: why dont you initialise  `.datepicker()`  with localization ` $('.dt').datepicker($.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] 
    )`

Comment: On AppInit() ? I will try

Edit : 
work it into a blank page , but not in the project :(

Comment: if possible can you create a jsfiddle , http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mcw0x3eq/

Comment: My JS function is call like this :

    <dx:ASPxGlobalEvents ID="geCFE" runat="server">
        <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="CFE_EC" />
    </dx:ASPxGlobalEvents>

Comment: i just added  a french localisation file  here and its working fine, https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mcw0x3eq/2/

Answer (score 0):

You never actually set the datepicker's options to the localized settings in `$.datepicker.regional["fr"]` (notice that this is simply an array of values -- you need to pass it to the widget proper). Use:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
```

or

```
$('.dt').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
```

Here's an update on your fiddle (also added the external libraries): https://jsfiddle.net/rq5j9j9v/